# OBIEE Parent Child Hierarchy in Visual Analyzer

Tags: parent, hierarchy, analyzer, obiee

OBIEE Visual Analyzer doesn't seem to recognize my parent/child hierarchy. That same hierarchy works fine when I use the Analysis and Interactive reporting tool. I have a level based hierarchy that works though. Does Visual Analyzer support parent/child hierarchies?

Also, what's the difference between the Visual Analyzer and the Analysis and Interactive Reporting tool? They both appear to do the same thing.

OBIEE Visual Analyzer vs. Analysis and Interactive Reporting
[image: Image: OBIEE Visual Analyzer vs. Analysis and Interactive Reporting]